# state of service can't be mutated in the component's unit test jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a component that consumes a resource from a service.

```
export class BarService {
age: string = '';
private dare$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
delete() {
  throw new Error('Delete');
}
dare = this.dare$.asObservable();

setDare(flag: boolean) {
  this.dare$.next(flag);
}

getVision() {
  //some http call 
  return of({ name: 'Andrew' });
}
//some http call 
getVisions = of({ name: 'ion' });
}
```

And in component what consumes this service.

```
 ...
  ngOnInit() {
this._bar.getVisions
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() => this._bar.getVision()),
    tap((value: any) => (this.dare = value.name)),
    catchError((err) => {
      this.error = true;
      console.log(err);

      return EMPTY;
    })
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
}
 ...
```

In my test

```
  beforeEach(() => {
barService = jasmine.createSpyObj(
  'BarService',
  {
    getVision: of('Ion'),
  },
  {
    getVisions: getError(),
    age: '41',
    dare: of({}),
  }
);
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [BarComponent],
  providers: [
    ...
    { provide: BarService, useValue: barService },
  ],
}).compileComponents();

fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BarComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
});
```

Here you'll find a benchmark created in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-dmb8rf?file=foo%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fbar%2Fbar.component.ts,foo%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fbar%2Fbar.component.html,foo%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fbar%2Fbar.component.spec.ts)

how can I change the state of these 2 observables 3 times, in different IT. I managed to change them but the problem is I can't find consistency in what I find: sometimes it works one way, and sometimes it works differently. Please help those who have more experience with jasmine :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your `stackblitz` link seems to be broken.

To change the value of the observables, I would use a `BehaviorSubject`. Something like this:

```
let barService: BarService;
// Declare behavior subjects
getVisionSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>('Ion');
dareSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
...
 // Assign behavior subjects to the spies
 beforeEach(() => {
  barService = jasmine.createSpyObj(
  'BarService',
  {
    getVision: getVisionSubject.asObservable(),
  },
  {
    getVisions: getError(),
    age: '41',
    dare: dareSubject.asObservable(),
  }
);
...
// change them in tests
it('abc', () => {
  getVisionSubject.next('blah');
  dareSubject.next({ a: 1 });
  ...
});

it('def', () => {
  getVisionSubject.next('yada');
  dareSubject.next({ b: 2 });
  ...
});
```

Comment: I updated the link for stackblitz